# What happens when a view has no constraints when using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

While browsing the documentation on Auto Layout, I was wondering what happens when a view doesn't have constraints. Does the Auto Layout system automatically add constraints to the view or does the system fall back on using an autorezing mask?

When a view doesn't have any constraints, Xcode tells you in the **Size Inspector** that at build time explicit left, top, width, and height constraints are generated for the view. However, when I log the view's constraints in the view controller's `viewDidAppear:` method, the `constraints` array is empty. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

What did you log, and what did you put in your storyboard? If I drag a label into a controller then log `self.view.constraints` in viewDidAppear, I get this,

```
2014-05-21 22:07:44.114 blah029347[3743:60b] (
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8d33f50 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:|-(95)-[UILabel:0x8d32470](LTR)   (Names: '|':UIView:0x8d32290 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8d34230 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:|-(177)-[UILabel:0x8d32470]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x8d32290 )>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8d342e0 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' H:[UILabel:0x8d32470(42)]>",
    "<NSIBPrototypingLayoutConstraint:0x8d34310 'IB auto generated at build time for view with fixed frame' V:[UILabel:0x8d32470(21)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8d33cc0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x8d33460(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8d31690 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x8d33460]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x8d32290 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8d31700 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x8d338d0(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x8d34340 _UILayoutGuide:0x8d338d0.bottom == UIView:0x8d32290.bottom>"
)
```

So, as you can see, the system does add constraints.

Answer (score 0):

If a view doesn't have any constraints then they will be generated for you based off the autoresizing mask.  If you add a view and set its `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoContraints` property to NO then you'll get a random location for the view.  With no constraints to satisfy then any values for its frame will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t supply any constraints at all, Xcode automatically assigns a set of default constraints, known as the **automatic constraints**. It does this at compile time when your app is built, not at design time. Auto Layout in Xcode 5 works hard to stay out of your way while you’re designing your user interfaces.